# cloned table row needs to use same function as the original

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been struggling with this for several days now.  I've got a search feature that works great, but now I need to allow users to click an add button to search for multiple things on the page.  Unfortunately,when I clone the table row (I'm changing the id's and necessary names) the new search doesn't work.  I can create an exact duplicate of the row in the html and they both work fine, but the cloned row doesn't whether it has the same id's or not.  I think it has something to do with the jquery dom, but I honestly don't understand the dom or jquery very well at all.

Honestly it's fairly complex to explain it all, so I created a jsfiddle that illustrates it perfectly.  You'll notice if you click on "click here" on either of the first two rows the search box opens, but if you click add, and the try to open the search box on the newly created (cloned) row it doesn't work.  I'd really like to only change this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var count = $("table.people tr").length;
        $("#Add").click(function () {
            count++;
            var $clone = $("#people_table tbody tr:first").clone();
            $clone.attr({
                id: function(_, id) { return id.slice(0, - 0) + count},
                style: "display:block;", // remove "display:none"
            });
            $clone.find("input,select").each(function () {
                var name = $(this).attr("name").replace("row[0]", "row[" + count + "]");
                $(this).attr("name", name);
            });
            $clone.find("option").each(function() {
                $(this).val("").attr("id", function(_, id) { return id + count });
            });
        $("#people_table tbody").append($clone);
            alert(onDomChange);
       });
    });
```

Mostly because the other code in the fiddle is used in multiple places (and working smoothly) on my site and I'd prefer to keep things as uniform as possible.

[Link to the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jasonobrown/qk78bfxh/2/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `.clone()` with `.clone(true)` which will deep clone the object including event handlers